# how to use an array from a select function in php

Tags: php, mysql

Am trying to INSERT the values from different option i have in the SELECT function i have below of the three different artist,but its not inserting it into the table i have in mysql,Am i doing it wrong? or there is other way to fetch the different option from the select function and inserting them in the mysql table?.
Any help please.Thank you

```
Artist1:<select name="role[]"><option></option>
<option>Actor</option>
<option>Director</option>
<option>Writer</option></select>

Artist2:<select name="role[]"><option></option>
<option>Actor</option>
<option>Director</option>
<option>Writer</option></select>

Artist3:<select name="role[]"><option></option>
<option>Actor</option>
<option>Director</option>
<option>Writer</option></select>
```

//this is my php code

```
$role=$_POST['role'];
$role = array();

if(count($role) > 0) {
    mysql_query('INSERT INTO movie_artists (job) VALUES ' . implode(',', $role));
}
```

Comment: use different name for select.

Comment: instead of using role[] for each of the three select function then i should just use maybe role1,role2,role3? is that what yu mean? @YogeshSuthar

Comment: Yes , use different name like role1,role2,role3 and if any of these select is having multiple selection for this use array like role1[] else use just role1.

Comment: and remove this `$role = array();` also from your code. It is assigning blank array to $role variable.

Answer (score 0):

```
$role=$_POST['role'];
$role = array();

if(count($role) > 0) {
    $job=implode(',', $role);
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO movie_artists(job) VALUES('". $job ."')");
}
```

Comment: i have tried it but its still not working,thank you for the help though @vikram

Comment: $role = array();
$role=$_POST['role'];
This is what i changed on $role. Is there any other change i should make on $role or what do you mean i should check on the value of $role? @vikram

Answer (score 0):

you are assiging value to `$role` so initially it will contain `$_POST['role']` but then `$role = array()` will refer to null array so
it should be like this

```
$role = array();
$role=$_POST['role'];

if(count($role) > 0) {
 mysql_query('INSERT INTO movie_artists (job) VALUES('". implode(',', $role) ."')");
}
```